# Is there any way to get the approximate location where my Azure application is being served from?

Tags: azure, geolocation

I am deploying applications to the 6 regions supported by Microsoft Azure, and would like to have a little bit more information about where the files are being served from, as I am trying to correlate HTTP download times from various locations around the world with the location of where they're being served.

Unfortunately, when I put the host IP addresses through any of the common Geolocation tools, they either are unresolvable or all resolve to the center of the North America!

I can understand why MS don't want to be too explicit on where http traffic originates from, but an approximate location would be useful - is this possible?

Comment: MikeWo's provided an answer, but wanted to add that tracert will give you much more insight into where/how the data is getting routed.

Comment: Well, I tried tracert and, perhaps it's a lack of understanding of how the routing is working within the Azure infrastructure, but I could not determine anything useful... and it always ended up resolving to a final IP of somewhere in Seattle.

Comment: right the owner of the IP isn't that useful, but if you look at the various routers there's a convention of using country/airport names/abbreviations e.g., xe-3-0-0-0.hkn-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net, note "hkn" for Hong Kong.  That said, after reading your other comments, you're not going to get down to your 50 mile radius. What's driving that level of granularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answer on the Windows Azure Trust Center site: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/privacy/

Asia: East (Hong Kong) and Southeast (Singapore)
Europe: North (Ireland) and West (Netherlands)
United States: North Central (Illinois), South Central (Texas), East (Virginia), and West (California)

It that close enough?

By the way, technically there are three regions (United States, Asia and Europe).  Each Data Center within the same region is called a Sub-Region.  The two new data centers in the Unites States were announced on April 5th.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this is also something I was not aware of... however it too is a little on the inaccurate side... however, I can see that I'm going to struggle to get better :)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very easy to get the approximate location based on the IP. Simply compare the IP of your hosted service (resolve yourapp.cloudapp.net) with the official [Windows Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29840).

Comment: Thanks for this - not aware it existed... however, it doesn't really help me as I want to be more precise than "Northern Europe" etc. I guess down to within 50miles of a town would be about right for me.

Comment: If I could say that two answers were correct, I would, but I think the other answer gives me a little more (although not as much as I'd like) accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

Latest Blogpost related to the ip-ranges: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/08/14/windows-azure-datacenter-ip-ranges.aspx as the other ms-link seems to be dead...